# Link php docker to host mysql

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www
    - ./src/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
  links:
    - php
php:
  image: nmcteam/php56
  volumes:
    - ./src/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
    - ./src:/var/www
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: sameersbn/mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - DB_NAME=demoDb
   - DB_USER=demoUser
   - DB_PASS=demoPass
```

Everything works fine but what I would like is to link php to mysql installed on host machine. Is there a way I could achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You could link the mysql volume like it says in the documentation: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#internal-mysql-server .

Or you can find the ip and access it as an external mysqlserver. 
Default networking mode is bridge, so the ip should be accessable. see this link to see how to find the docker host ip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: Thank you. You helped me in finding my answer.

Comment: No problem.. i'll add it as an answer until you put in a complete answer yourself..  @magarusu

Answer (score 1):

You could link the mysql volume like it says in the documentation: http://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#internal-mysql-server . Or one can bind the sockets(see comment below)

Or you can find the ip and access it as an external mysqlserver. Default networking mode is bridge, so the ip should be accessable.
 See the "[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)" on how to find the IP

Comment: Alternatively, bind-mount the MySQL socket inside the container, and use the socket to connect to MySQL, e.g. `- /var/run/mysql.sock:/tmp/mysql.sock` inside the `volumes` section, to make the socket available as `/tmp/mysql.sock` inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the best all around answer as it's less possible to create any new security issues:

Mount mysqld.sock from the host to inside the container.

Find the location of the mysql.sock file on the host running mysql:

```
netstat -ln | awk '/mysql(.*)?\.sock/ { print $9 }'
```

Mount that file to where it's expected in the docker:

```
docker run -v /hostpath/to/mysqld.sock:/containerpath/to/mysqld.sock
```

Possible locations of mysqld.sock:

```
/tmp/mysqld.sock
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484147/2245680

I took a different approach as I only need this for development and I changed the networking mode so that every container could communicate with the host. To achieve this you can do something like this in your `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www
  net: "host"
php:
  image: nmcteam/php56
  volumes:
    - ./src/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
    - ./src:/var/www
  net: "host"
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#net